# Is there any way I can set CSS properties purely as a fallback for others not being browser compatible?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My website was rendering fine in all browsers until I tested it in the Internet Explorer. My menubar moved entirely to the left covering my logo and all the parts that used Grid did not show up anymore.

I figured out the exact replacements I would have to make in order to be IE browser compatible. However, just placing them in my CSS after my original nav and grid properties, overwrites them in general on my website, which I do not want as I still want my originally coded website on other browsers to stay the same.

Is there another way to create a fallback just for the IE browser or how to solve these issues?

E.g. my grid attached - my header code is quite long as it includes a responsive toggle menu as well - as well as media queries for both!

In summary - I want the browser to ignore the CSS properties I set before and paste new ones instead - in case of failure by the browser.

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 500px 500px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 100px;
}

.grid__item {
  background-color: var(--violet-lighter);
}

/*start internet explorer grid fallback*/
.grid {
  display: inline-block;
}

.grid_item {
  width: 50%;
}


/*end internet explorer grid fallback*/
```

I also tried the following without success - in this case IE ignores the changes all together:

```
.grid {
  display: inline-block; /*IE fallback*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 500px 500px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 100px;
}

.grid__item {
  background-color: var(--violet-lighter);
}
```

Comment: The general technique is to put the CSS for older browsers _first_, and then override that with later CSS for browsers that support the newer CSS.

Comment: @Alohci Thanks! In my 2nd example, I have put my IE fallback first, right? But that did not work. In that case, it ignored the newer CSS features altogether in browsers that supported it

Answer (score 1):

You could try browser duct-typing with javascript/jquery and giving the `html` or the `body` a class name of that specific browser. In this case I have used class names:

- Opera      = `.is-opera`
- Firefox    = `.is-firefox`
- Safari     = `.is-safari`
- IE         = `.is-internet-explorer`
- Edge       = `.is-edge`
- Chrome     = `.is-chrome`
- E-Chromium = `is-edge-chromium`

Its important to notice that relying on duct-typing **is not** a good idea and if your website needs to be accessible by all the browsers, your original code should be written in a way that it supports legacy browser.

To know what you can and cannot use can be found here:
[Can I use - Check CSS browser support](https://caniuse.com/)

```
// Detect which browser is being used:

jQuery( document ).ready(function() 
{

    // Where the class will be set, in this case to the body:
    var body = $('body');

    // Opera
    var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    if(isOpera){
        body.addClass('is-opera');
    }

    // Firefox
    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    if(isFirefox){
        body.addClass('is-firefox');
    }

    // Safari
    var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && window['safari'].pushNotification));
    if(isSafari){
        body.addClass('is-safari');
    }

    // Internet Explorer:
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
    if(isIE){
        body.addClass('is-internet-explorer');
    }

    // Microsoft edge
    var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
    if(isEdge){
        body.addClass('is-edge');
    }

    // Chrome
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);
    if(isChrome){
        body.addClass('is-chrome');
    }

    // Edge Chromium
    var isEdgeChromium = isChrome && (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edg") != -1);
    if(isEdgeChromium){
        body.addClass('is-edge-chromium');
    }

});
```

After adding the javascript code, you can test it with your browser and see if the `body` gets a new class called `.is-xxx`. Then just make edits for problematic browsers like this. (I used what you tried to change here as an example with the `.is-internet-explorer` class)

```
.is-internet-explorer .grid {
  display: inline-block;
}

.is-internet-explorer .grid_item {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I personally have given up on people who still use internet-explorer. But If its required, then it's required. What can we do. =)

Comment: Thanks a lot @erecodes! I am just today starting to learn Javascript so I will explore this more then. Sadly, I have not seen any purely CSS fallbacks that worked yet though. IE is retiring this June but there are still too many browsers who do not support incredibly useful features like Grid..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about fallbacks but you can write IE-specific CSS in a separate file and then use conditional comment in this way:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="only-ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You can refer to this article for a better understanding.
https://www.browserstack.com/guide/create-browser-specific-css

Comment: There are much better ways of browser fallbacks

Comment: @ZachJensz then please enlighten us

Comment: Jen Simmons has some great [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7msERxu7ivg). (I didn't downvote you btw)